# Why does Agda give error "expected: ℕ, actual: ℕ"

Tags: agda, dependent-type

When I write the following function is agda,

```
f : (A : Set) → (a : A) → ℕ
f ℕ n = n
```

I expect the error to say that I have not specified all cases.

Instead, I get this error:

```
Type mismatch:
expected: ℕ
actual: ℕ
when checking that the expression n
has type ℕ
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a more recent version of Agda (I'm using 2.5.4) you get a more informative error:

```
ℕ !=< ℕ of type Set
(because one is a variable and one a defined identifier)
when checking that the expression n has type ℕ
```

The problem is that the pattern of a function definition (on the left of the equals sign) can consist of only constructors, variables, and dot patterns, but not types such as `ℕ`. Since `ℕ` is not a valid pattern, Agda assumes (perhaps confusingly) that it is a new variable called `ℕ` of type `Set`, thus shadowing the actual type `ℕ` of natural numbers. Now the error makes sense, since the type of `n` (which is `ℕ` the variable) is not equal to the expected return type (which is the type `ℕ` of natural numbers).